# Excel - Return the date the most recent promotion occurred

Tags: excel, max, sumifs

I am trying to develop a formula that will return the date a person reached a certain "level" as shown in the picture at the link:
[image: Example]

The reference table has 4 columns: Name (col. A), Code (col. B), Date (col. C), and Level (col. D). "Name" contains the first name of an employee (either Dave or Joy). "Code" records the type of action that occurred (1 = Promotion, 2&3 do not matter). "Date" records the date the action occurred.  "Level" records the pay level an employee has attained (the higher the level number, the greater the pay).

The query table has 3 columns: "Name" is the same as in the reference table.  "Level" is the same as the reference table. "Date Level Reached" should house a formula that will return the "Date" from the reference table at which the relevant employee was promoted to a level.

In the picture, I am trying to return the date where **Dave** (cell F3) reached level **14** (cell G3). The answer should be "10/1/2019" but I have not been able to find a formula that returns that answer.

Among other things, I tried the sumifs with max array formula discussed at the link below, but could not configure in such a way that didn't either return "0" or didn't sum multiple dates.  Any helpful advice would be greatly appreciated.

[Using Max function result in SumIFS Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38950559/using-max-function-result-in-sumifs-excel)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, this will work. Adjust ranges to suit. This will find the earliest date, which I assume you want as opposed to the first instance?

```
=MINIFS(C2:C9,A2:A9,F3,D2:D9,G3)
```